# Stored Procedure that updates fields with different values

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update

I am using SQL Server.

I need to create a stored procedure that will update the Data field (table bellow) with different value for every ID value. (the values in the Data fields depend on the user input).

```
ID | Data
---------
1     | NULL

2     | NULL

3     | NULL
```

For example:
if ID = 1, Data should be "Test1"

The ID and Data pairs should somehow be input parameters to the stored procedures.

Is this possible, or I'll have to call simple update procedure for every ID/Data pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use XML for sending data for multiple rows. For your current problem prepare (generate dynamically) an xml like below.

```
 '<NewDataSet><Table><Id>1</Id><Data>test1</Data></Table><Table><Id>2</Id><Data>test2</Data></Table></NewDataSet>'
```

Then Prepare a procedure like below.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[UpdateMultipleRecords]    
 (                
 @XmlString VARCHAR(MAX)  
 )              
 AS                      
 BEGIN    
 SET NOCOUNT ON;     



 CREATE TABLE #DATA    
 (              
 Id int,    
 Data varchar(50) NULL 

 )    

 DECLARE @DocHandle int    
 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @DocHandle OUTPUT, @XmlString    

 INSERT INTO #DATA    
 SELECT Id,Data
 FROM OPENXML (@DocHandle, '/NewDataSet/Table',2)    
 WITH    
 (                    
 Id int,    
 Data varchar(50)  
 )    
  EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @DocHandle                

 UPDATE [dbo].[Table1]  SET DATA=D.Data
 FROM [dbo].[Table1] T  INNER JOIN #DATA D ON T.ID=D.Id

IF (SELECT OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#DATA')) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #DATA    

END
```

And call the procedure as

```
[UpdateMultipleRecords] '<NewDataSet><Table><Id>1</Id><Data>Test1</Data></Table><Table><Id>2</Id><Data>Test2</Data></Table></NewDataSet>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need user-defined table types for this:

Try this:

```
-- test table
create table yourtable(id int not null, data [varchar](256) NULL)

GO

-- test type
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[usertype] AS TABLE(
    [id] [int] not null,
    [Data] [varchar](256) NULL
)
GO

-- test procedure
create procedure p_test
(
@tbl dbo.[usertype] READONLY
) as
BEGIN
  UPDATE yourtable
  SET data = t.data
  FROM yourtable
  JOIN
  @tbl t
  ON yourtable.id = t.id
END

go

-- test data

insert yourtable(id)
values(1),(2),(3)

go
```

Test of script:

```
declare @t [dbo].[usertype]
insert @t values(1,'hello'),(2,'world')

exec p_test @t

select * from yourtable
```

Result:

```
id  data
1   hello
2   world
3   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another table with your values as a Source for the update

```
update t
set
 Data = src.Data
from tableDestination t
inner join sourceTable src on
    t.ID = src.ID
```

Comment: The data is dynamic (depends on the user input). So if I use another table, I need to insert all of the data to that temporary table, and than update the original table. Is this your idea?

Comment: @Programmer do you want stored procedure to update data column value based on id ??

Comment: Yes,  but I need multiple updates in the same stored procedure. Also, the number of updates is dynamic. For example, input parameters in the stored procedure can be: 1, Test; 2, Test2. Or it can be: 3, Test; 5, Test1; 7, Test6.